# SSH to a remote host that is not reachable directly

Tags: macos, ssh, socat

There is a host A that is not accessible from my local network. But there is a host B which I can access via SSH and A is visible to B.
So I setup an SSH tunnel and try to access A via B

```
ssh -N -D 7070 username@HOST_B
```

my ~/.ssh/config looks like

```
host HOST_A
    ProxyCommand socat - PROXY:127.0.0.1:7070:%h:%p,proxyport=7070
```

When I run the following command

```
ssh -v username@HOST_A
```

I got the following error.

```
debug1: identity file /Users/leo/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: identity file /Users/leo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/leo/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/leo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
2013/05/21 22:19:13 socat[4537] E proxy_connect: connection closed by proxy
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

There is no /etc/hosts.allow or /etc/hosts.deny on my machine.
I am using mac OS.

Comment: It sounds like you want to go from local host to B, and then from B to A? If so, you could always `ssh -t B ssh A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking `socat` to connect to a HTTP proxy, but the ssh tunnel you set up is a SOCKS proxy. Tell `socat` to connect to the SOCKS proxy:

```
host HOST_A
    ProxyCommand socat - SOCKS4:127.0.0.1:7070:%h:%p,proxyport=7070
```

(Other SOCKS options may be available --- check `man socat` for the particular socat you have installed.)

But usually you don't want to have to setup the ssh tunnel in advance. The usual way is to use netcat on HOST_B:

```
host HOST_A
    ProxyCommand /usr/bin/ssh username@HOST_B /bin/nc %h %p
```

(Changes pathnames to ssh and netcat as necessary.)

demure's `ssh -t HOST_B ssh HOST_A` method also works, but cannot be configured in `~/.ssh/config`.